# How to recreate containers with Docker Compose on a Swarm Cluster of multiple nodes?

Tags: node.js, docker, dns, containers, docker-compose

I ran into [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2444) issue when I had only 1 node in my Swarm cluster and when I tried to recreate my web app container on this node (I want to deploy a new version of my Node.JS web app which is listening on port 80)

The problem is that Swarm stops the old container first but **doesn't remove it**, and then tries to create the new one and because Swarm tracks the port constraints for stopped containers as well, it thinks that on my node port 80 is still in use (by the stopped container):

```
Recreating 41910b0283eb_41910b0283eb_41910b0283eb_vagrant_web_1
ERROR: unable to find a node with port 80 available
```

There could be 2 solutions to this problem:

1. Before every deployment, I can do `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose rm` which stops and removes **every** running container - this will free up the port 80 for Swarm as well.
2. Another solution is to have multiple nodes and relax. When compose recreates your container, Swarm will automatically find a random node where nobody uses port 80 and starts the new container on this other node.

I can work with the solution 1. but I would like to know how to make it work when I have multiple nodes.

My problem with the 2. approach is that  usually a web application needs to have a fix IP what I can use for domain registration. If Swarm deploys my web app to a randomly chosen node then how can I workaround this problem?

I could use [Round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) but I'm not sure if it would help because in this case if I have for example 3 nodes in my cluster, I need to have one instance of my web app on every node. But if this is the case, then I wouldn't run into the same problem? Swarm would think that somebody still using the port 80 so it won't find any node with port 80 available.

How to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the time there is a load balancer in front of the application. The DNS entry points at the load balancer, and you can have it reconfigure itself when the containers stop and start.

There are a few projects out there that handle that for you from `docker events`. Here are just a few of the ones I know of:

- https://github.com/ehazlett/interlock
- https://github.com/containous/traefik
- https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy